# Argument replacement not working for type object

Tags: magento2, object-manager, code, di.xml

I am trying to replace an object using Argument Replacement but unfortunately I am unable to do so for type:object.

Every time I am getting error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type 
Error occurred when creating object: Narendra\VirtualType\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Narendra\VirtualType\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor
```

```
#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Narendra\Virtual...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Narendra\Virtual...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/ActionFactory.php:44]
#3 Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory->create('Narendra\Virtual...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php:306]
#4 Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004565e8fa0000000078c8f6e1#, array('moduleFrontName' => 'vt', 'actionPath' => 'index', 'actionName' => 'index')) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php:167]
#5 Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004565e8fa0000000078c8f6e1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:95]
#6 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004565e8fa0000000078c8f6e1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#7 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004565e8fa0000000078c8f6e1#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#8 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004565e8fa0000000078c8f6e1#) called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#9 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000004565ee820000000078c8f6e1#, &Closure#000000004565ecd20000000078c8f6e1#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004565e8fa0000000078c8f6e1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#10 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004565e8fa0000000078c8f6e1#) called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#11 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000004565ee820000000078c8f6e1#, &Closure#000000004565ecd20000000078c8f6e1#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004565e8fa0000000078c8f6e1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#12 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004565e8fa0000000078c8f6e1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#13 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004565e8fa0000000078c8f6e1#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004565e8fa0000000078c8f6e1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000004565ee0a0000000078c8f6e1#) called at [index.php:47]
```

I tried replacing the argument for type string and it worked perfectly for me.

What I have done is:

**Created a controller Index:**

```
public $argument1;

public $scaler1;

public function __construct(Context $context, BlockRepositoryInterface $argument1, $scaler1='narendra')
{
    $this->argument1 = $argument1;
    $this->scaler1 = $scaler1;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    echo $this->scaler1;exit;
}
```

**app/code/Narendra/VirtualType/etc/di.xml**

> This does not works

```
<type name="Narendra\VirtualType\Controller\Index\Index">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="argument1" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

> This works for me

```
<type name="Narendra\VirtualType\Controller\Index\Index">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="scaler1" xsi:type="string">from di xml file</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: Can you edit the question add the whole exception @Narendra

Comment: @PrachiSaxena: I have updated my question and have added whole error, please have a look

Comment: Did you tried removing content of generated folder and check if the error is still there?

Comment: yes i removed it and tried but not sure why error keeps on populating.
rm -rf generated/* && bin/magento c:f

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you trying to replace an argument type of a function, then you must remember that the **replaced type class** should also able to create **the old argument type object**.

## Lets me give an example:

On your question, your `argument1's`  type is `Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface`.

So, you must have to use those interfaces Or Classes which extend `Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface` as replace the type of `argument1`.

like: `Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository` which implement `Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface`

But you have to try to use `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` Argument Replacement of `argument1`.That's why you are getting the error.

**So, replace types is important during the implementing of type argument.**

At Second case, `scaler1` is the type of string and **replace** type also **string**. So it is working.

Comment: Seems as if you are correct. But I am still wondering what are the classes in argument that we can replace and what are that we cant. I changed di.xml like this and it worked for me without any error:
<type name="Narendra\VirtualType\Controller\Index\Index">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="argument1" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

Comment: I have created this module only to make understanding on Argument Replacement. I am thinking that any argument in the constructor class can be replaced with any different class.
If you can provide me any reference link from where i may get better insight i would really apericiate. tnks

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try in the following format this example is similar to yours and working for me:

```
<type name="Amasty\ShopbyBase\Model\UrlBuilder">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="urlAdapters" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="base" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adapter" xsi:type="object">\Amasty\ShopbyBase\Model\UrlBuilder\Adapter</item>
                <item name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">100</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: hmmm, not sure if that is going to work as the argument that I want to replace is not an array. But will give a try

Comment: you have to modify it as per your implementation I am not saying copy paste will work. But structure will be like above.